# What is the embedded server used in Apache Jackrabbit-standalone?

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit, embedded-server

I believe in jackrabbit-standalone jar, there should be an application server embedded in order to serve web content.

I was trying to find what is the exact embedded server used in jackrabbit-standalone.jar. Based on the documentation on jackrabbit-standalone it does not mention any thing about it.

https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/standalone-server.html

Do any one know about which embedded server it uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes use of [eclipse jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).

You can validate it by digging on project's [source code](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit) and especially [jackrabbit-standalone](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit/tree/trunk/jackrabbit-standalone) module.

Snippet from [pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit/blob/trunk/jackrabbit-standalone/pom.xml#L58) of aforesaid module:

```
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <instructions>
        <Export-Package>
          org.apache.jackrabbit.standalone
        </Export-Package>
        <Embed-Dependency>
          *;inline=*.txt|*.html|*.jsp|*.xml|*.jar|*.properties|remoting/**|bootstrap/**|javax/**|repackage/**|images/**|com/**|ch/**|jline/**|Resources/**|css/**|schema*/**|EDU/**|error/**|org/**|META-INF/*.tld|META-INF/maven/**|META-INF/services/**|WEB-INF/config.xml|WEB-INF/*.properties|WEB-INF/templates/**
        </Embed-Dependency>
        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
        <Main-Class>org.apache.jackrabbit.standalone.Main</Main-Class> <- This is the main class of the jar
      </instructions>
    </configuration>
    ...
```

Snippet from [org.apache.jackrabbit.standalone.Main](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit/blob/6288f139ebfd82b2ef6ab4a804ea59fb93c277e4/jackrabbit-standalone-components/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/standalone/Main.java#L184):

```
 ...
 import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
 ...
 private final Server server = new Server();
 ...
 server.start();
 ...
```